# Detect Image Load Cancelation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm currently working on a page that loads several images sequentially using `setTimeout` and `onLoad`.  Basically when an image finishes loading, `onLoad` is triggered, which starts another image loading via a `setTimeout` call.  Unfortunately, if an image load is interrupted for some reason, such as a subsequent `ajax` call, onload is never called and any images left to be loaded are not loaded.  Is there any way in javascript to detect this situation?  I've attempted to hook into `onError` and `onAbort` (on the image tag) and neither of these seem to be called.

```
  queuePhotos: function(options)
{
  this.init();
  this.photo_urls = options.photo_urls;
  this.photo_size = options.size
  this.max_width = options['max_width'];
  this.max_height = options['max_height'];
  this.containers = options['containers'];
  yd = YAHOO.util.Dom;
  photo_tags = yd.getElementsByClassName('image_stub', 'div');
  for( i in photo_tags )
  {
    //create new image
    photo = new Image();
    this.queue.push( { tag: photo_tags[i], photo: photo } ); 
  }
  setTimeout(photoLoader.prepareNextPhoto, 1);
},

prepareNextPhoto: function()
{
  photo_tag_and_image = photoLoader.queue.shift();
  if(photo_tag_and_image)
  {
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(photo_tag_and_image.photo, "load", photoLoader.appendPhoto, photo_tag_and_image, photoLoader);
    photo_tag_and_image.photo.src = photoLoader.photo_urls[photo_tag_and_image.tag.id];
  }
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An AJAX call shouldn't cancel the loading of images. There could be something else going on here...

I don't think that you can readily detect the load failure of an image. You could fire off a timer with a certain timeout threshold to deem an image as failed if your timeout timer expires before you get the load event from the image.

Comment: The "something else" could be if the AJAX call sets new innerHTML on the element containing the loading images, or its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can call onload and onerror

```
myImage.onload = function(){ alert("loaded"); };
myImage.onerror = function(){ alert("whoops"); };
```

Eric